# Problem deploying Ruby on Rails 7 app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to deploy my project to Heroku and I have this error:

`Running: rake assets:precompile rake aborted! SyntaxError: /tmp/build_c99702b3/config/environments/production.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected constant, expecting 'do' or '{' or '(' ...oku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY']`

Although I have seen very similar errors and problems described here, nothing is working for me. I have `credentials.yml.enc` file and `master.key` file. Everything is working fine on localhost:3000,but when I try to deploy it I received this error. I am running VMWare VM Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (although I have run it as well on 20.04 LTS) on Windows 10 machine. Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.1.1'
gem 'rails', '~> 7.0.3'
gem 'sprockets-rails'
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1'
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
gem 'importmap-rails'
gem 'turbo-rails'
gem 'stimulus-rails'
gem 'tailwindcss-rails'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]
gem 'bootsnap', require: false
gem 'devise', '~> 4.7'
gem 'finnhub_ruby', '~> 1.1.16'
gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: %i[development test]
group :development, :test do
    gem 'debug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
    %w[rspec-core rspec-expectations rspec-mocks rspec-rails rspec-support].each do |lib|
      gem lib, git: "https://github.com/rspec/#{lib}.git", branch: 'main'
    end
end

group :development do
    gem 'web-console'
end
```

I also try to use `.env` file and had my master key defined there as well like this:

`ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxx'`

but it did not help as well.

Could you, please, let me know what is the problem and if somebody could provide detailed instructions on how to do this, I mean especially where and how the master key has to be placed, so it could deploy to Heroku?
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: How `config/environments/production.rb:22` looks?

Comment: Yeah, I had this:

`heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY']`

but realized that it should not be there. I have to enter it at the console, but I do not know when. Do I have to execute the command after I do `heroku create` using CLI or? Please, elaborate if you know. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need this command in the `productionu.rb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`heroku config:set` is CLI command, you don't need to put this line to your `production.rb`

If you need to set this env variable to Heroku just execute in your terminal after `heroku create` command and before deploy

```
heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=`cat config/master.key`
```

or

```
heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY="$(< config/master.key)"
```

Comment: I just did this. `heroku create`
`heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY='cat config/master.key'`

`Setting RAILS_MASTER_KEY and restarting ⬢ salty-inlet-83040... done, v3
RAILS_MASTER_KEY: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
After that I did `git heroku push dev:main` and got the error: 

remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        SyntaxError: /tmp/build_5320c124/config/environments/production.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected constant, expecting `do' or '{' or '('
remote:        ...oku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY']

Comment: Here is the update. I cleaned up the production file and set the RAILS_MASTER_KEY using the console. I deploy it to Heroku. There are no errors in the log file, but when I start the app it says: We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information. It seems from `heroku logs -t` that some images are not present in the asset pipeline. I did not precompile the assets. How and when I have to do this?

Comment: Please create new question with debug info

Comment: Your answer is correct and my issue has been resolved. Thank you! Yes, now it is a different problem and this case should be closed! I accepted your answer @mechnicov!